# regular expression: match any word until first space

Tags: regex

I have the following line:

```
hshd    household   8/29/2007   LB
```

I want to match anything that comes before the first space (whitespace).  So, in this case, I want to get back

```
hshd
```

Comment: What's wrong with splitting and getting the first elem?

Comment: Because the question may be part of a larger regex task. Say, to match (a_complex_regex_pattern) (whatever_word) (another_complex_regex_pattern).

Answer (score 454, accepted):

```
([^\s]+)
```

works

Comment: I would further prepend ^ to get the first word only

Comment: while generally correct, I think the need for `^` depends on particular language implementations or regexp. for example in Python you'd use `re.match` for this task.

Comment: This matches all the words and not just the first one, [see this example](http://regexr.com?32scv).

Comment: @RyanGates deselect Global and you will see that it works as intended and expected. Refer to SilentGhost for notes on language implementations if you're still having trouble.

Comment: It seems that if the string begins with a space, this will ignore the space and return the first word *after* the string. I would think that if the line beings with a space, it would just return an empty string.

Comment: Could `[^\s]+` be simplified to `\S+` ?

Comment: (^[^\s]+) is what you are looking for

Comment: Re: "works": hm, `echo "hshd    household   8/29/2007   LB" | grep -P '([^\s]+)'` leads to `hshd    household   8/29/2007   LB` instead of `hshd`. Any ideas? Grep version is 3.4.

Comment: Could you explain your answer

Answer (score 76):

This should do it:

```
^\S*
```

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps you could try `([^ ]+) .*`, which should give you everything to the first blank in your first group.

Comment: @ire_and_curses, on Sublime Text, that will skip the last word in a line. For some reason, this does not: ([^ ])+

Answer (score 12):

Derived from the answer of @SilentGhost I would use:

```
^([\S]+)
```

Check out this [interactive regexr.com page](http://regexr.com/4920f) to see the result and explanation for the suggested solution.

Answer (score 6):

for the entire line

```
^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+(?:\/\d+){2})\s+(\w+)$
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, that will be good solution: `/\S\w*/`

Answer (score 2):

I think, a word was created with more than one letters.
My suggestion is:

```
[^\s\s$]{2,}
```

Answer (score 1):

^([^\s]+) use this it correctly matches only the first word you can test this using this link 
https://regex101.com/

Comment: its derived from that answer.

Comment: Then explain why you think a new answer is required,  and explain any possible difference; but you will find that it is already discussed in the comments on the accepted answer. Also, the second highest voted answer is quite similar, but somewhat more elegant in that it prefers the simpler `\S` over the equivalent but clunky `[^\s]`.

Answer (score 1):

> (^\S+)

This did the trick for me. (/gm)

You could test it in [this](https://regex101.com/r/CEMZ3l/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
/(^\S+)/g
```

The sequence "\S+" in a regular expression indicates that one or more characters must match that are not white-space characters.

The quantifier "+" indicates to match one or more consecutive instances of the preceding character or group, whereas the shorthand character class "\S" matches any non-whitespace character.

Thus, "\S+" will match one or more consecutive non-whitespace characters.

(^) at the start, indicate that a match must occur at the beginning of the searched text.

and finally parentheses () are used for grouping.

[REGEX DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/1f043d205417).