# regex for first character before space

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to extract "d320" from the below string using regex in java using the below code 
n-us; micromax d320 build/kot49h)

```
    String m = "n-us; micromax d320 build/kot49h) ";
    String pattern = "micromax (.*)(\\d\\D)(.*) ";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m1 = r.matcher(m);
    if (m1.find()) {
        System.out.println(m1.group(1));


    }
```

but it is giving me the output as "d320 build/kot4" , i want only d320

Comment: `micromax (\\S+\\d)\\D` or `micromax (\\S+)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Please post answer as an answer :P

Comment: @TheLostMind tired of posting the same answer again and again for past 2 years..

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I know.. But still.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1400445/4229270

Comment: @TheLostMind I'm going to remove regex from my favourite tags.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - (80 million developers screaming ..)..  Nooooooo. Why God WHy? :P

Comment: @Himanshu - your question is not clear. You are trying to parse the word containing `d` or `D`. Right?

Comment: @TheLostMind Many new comers willing to contribute to this tag like [Stribizhev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew), vks, etc. So lets keep them a way to go.. Don't worry, main God anubhava is still here to watch all the regex questions..

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Lol.. So which tag now?

Comment: Now, `string.replaceFirst("\\bregex+or+string\\b", "django+or+google-app-engine", myfavtags);`

Comment: Do you want to match the third word, or the word following "micromax"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `micromax\\s(.*?)\\s` like this:

```
     String m = "n-us; micromax d320 build/kot49h) ";
    String pattern = "micromax\\s(.*?)\\s";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m1 = r.matcher(m);
    if (m1.find()) {
        System.out.println(m1.group(1));

    }
```

Output:

```
  d320
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not known whether you want the word after "micromax", or the word that starts with a letter and has all digits afterward, so here's both solutions:

To extract the word following "micromax":

```
String code = m.replaceAll(".*micromax\\s+(\\w+)?.*", "$1");
```

To extract the word that looks like "x9999":

```
String code = m.replaceAll(".*?\b([a-z]\\d+)?\b.*", "$1");
```

Both snippets will result in a blank string if is there's no match.