# (Python) changing date format from from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to extract a date from a string and change the date format from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd. Somehow I got it wrong.

I read through the links below to help me get there, but need a quick hand.

- [How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)
- [regular expression: match any word until first space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400431/regular-expression-match-any-word-until-first-space)

```
import re
import datetime

str = "2017/09/15 07:11:00"

x = re.match( r'([^\s]+)',str)
new_x = datetime.datetime.strptime("re.match( r'([^\s]+)',str)", "%Y/%m/%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(x)
print(new_x)
```

[(pic) for code and error type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALmT1.png)

Comment: Have you considered `.replace('-', '/')` (or vice versa depending on which you are actually trying to do)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current syntax is not valid, because you are passing the call to `re.match` as a literal string.  Instead, try doing a replacement on the date portion only via a regex replacement with a callback function:

```py
import re
import datetime

str = "2017/09/15 07:11:00"
output = re.sub(r'^(\S+)', lambda m: datetime.datetime.strptime(m.group(1), "%Y/%m/%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), str)
print(output)  # 2017-09-15 07:11:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I converted it using simple string slicing like this:

```
import datetime

string = "2017/09/15 07:11:00"
string = string[0:10]
new_x = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y/%m/%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(new_x)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to convert string to datetime object and than you can convert a datetime.

```
import datetime

str = "2017/09/15 07:11:00"

converted_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(str, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
print(converted_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

or if datetime object is not needed than you can just use a replace:

```
str = "2017/09/15 07:11:00"
str = str.replace("/", "-")
print(str)
```